# how to take input for a struct C++

Tags: c++, input, data-structures, struct

```
struct Patient
{
int priority;
char name[30];
char email[20];
char phone[10];
};
```

This is the method im using but gives an error.

```
    Patient ds; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout<<"Patient #"<<i<<": "<<endl;
    cout<<"Priority: ";
```

below in this "cin"

```
    cin>> ds[i].priority;
    cout<<endl<<"Name: ";
    cin.get(ds[i].name,30);
    cout<<endl<<"Email: ";
    cin.get(ds[i].email,20);
    cout<<endl<<"Phone: "<<endl;
    cin.get(ds[i].phone,10);
```

any help!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error you're getting. And why are you not using `std::string` for the strings?

Comment: `cin>> ds[i].priority;` : `d`should be an array, but is declared `Patient d`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string aString;
cout << "Input Name:" << endl; // Output
cin >> aString;                // Input and store in aString
```

So I would use `string` instead of `char []` in your `patient`, and the  you could do

```
cin >> patient.name;           // Input
cout << patient.name << endl;  // Output
```

For example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) you can find some more examples.